# Shaders not outputting anything when attribute location != 0

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have the following extremely simple vertex shader, when I render with it I get a blank screen:

```
#version 110

layout(location = 1) attribute vec3 position;

uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

void main() {
    vec4 eye = modelview_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projection_matrix * eye;
}
```

However, changing

`layout(location = 1) attribute vec3 position;` to

`layout(location = 0) attribute vec3 position;`

allows me to render correctly.  Here's my rendering function:

```
glUseProgram(program);

GLenum error;

glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUniformMatrix4fv(
    modelview_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelview));
glUniformMatrix4fv(
    projection_uniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
    position_attribute,
    3,
    GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE,
    0,
    (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(position_attribute);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, element_buffer);
glDrawElements(
    GL_TRIANGLES,
    monkey_mesh.indices.size(),
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
    (void*)0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(position_attribute);

glutSwapBuffers();
```

I obtain `position_attribute` through a call to `glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");`.  It contains the correct value in both cases (1 in the first case, 0 in the second).

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  I'm sure I'm able to render when `location == 0` only because I'm lucky and the data is written there by sheer luck but I can't figure out for the life of me what step I'm missing.

Comment: Apart from `#version 110` it looks surprisingly right... (in version 110 there was no `location` layouting specifier, but since it's forward compatible... (at least I think it is) it shouldn't be a problem).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Removing the version specifier or changing it doesn't fix the issue either.  I'm lost!

Comment: That's why I said "surprisingly". For things like this I (and others on SO) usually suspect the remnants of fixed attribute bindings that sometimes are still in the drivers. Are you using Core context and which version exactly? IIRC Explicit attrib locations went in in 3.3, so that might be a good start.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm setting this up with GLEW and checking `GLEW_VERSION_3_3` if that makes sense.

Comment: Any chance you're using an NVIDIA driver?  They're notorious for moving attributes locations around.

Comment: @radical7 Nope, AMD Radeon

Comment: @pwny: "`GLEW_VERSION_3_3`" That doesn't mean anything. That's a #define; the OpenGL version is a runtime issue.

Comment: @NicolBolas Is there a way I can request a specific version or check if my driver supports it?

Comment: @pwny that needs `ARB_create_context` WGL/GLX extension. W/o it you will get a stock context, which is usually Compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is not possible. GLSL version 1.10 does not support `layout` syntax at all. So your compiler should have rejected the shader. Therefore, either your compiler is not rejecting the shader and is therefore broken, or you are not loading the shader you think you are.

If it still doesn't work when using GLSL version 3.30 or higher (the first core version to support `layout(location=#)` syntax for attribute indices), then what you're seeing is the result of a different bug. Namely, the compatibility profile implicitly states that, to render with vertex arrays, you must either use attribute zero or `gl_Vertex`. The core profile has no such restrictions. However, this restriction was in GL for a while, so some implementations will still enforce it, even on the core profile where it doesn't exist.

So just use attribute zero. Or possibly switch to the core profile if you're not already using it (though I'd be surprised if an implementation actually implements the distinction correctly. Generally, it'll either be too permissive in compatibility or too restrictive in core).

Comment: So I was right about the compatibility cruft with fixed attribute locations!

Comment: I switched to `#version 330` and dropped the layout directives and I'm getting the expected results.  Thanks for your help, I didn't want to jump to blaming the implementation too fast but it seems my code wasn't the issue after all.

Comment: @pwny: No, your code was the issue; you can't use `#version 330`. Also, you shouldn't *stop* using the layout location directive. You should simply make sure that all your shaders use attribute 0. OpenGL isn't required to automatically assign an attribute to location 0.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok so if I understand correctly, I should still use location directives, but make sure I start at 0.  Should the locations be sequential as well or can I go `0, 2, 3`?